# What is a good leak detection tool for objective-c & MACOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know this question is subjective but I am brand new to Objective-C and the MacOS. Although I am trying to be diligent in my memory management I am sure my code is leaky. Can someone suggest a good tool to detect these leaks?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

There are *leaks* and then there are **leaks**.

Leaks is strictly defined as an allocation in memory for which there are no remaining references to said allocation and, thus, no way your app could use it again.   As Bogatyr said, The Leaks instrument does a great job of tracking these down.

However, you might find that your app is still growing over time, a sure sign of a an additional problem.  Regardless of whether or not it is truly a leak, such potentially unbounded growth in allocations is obvious very bad.

For that, use Heapshot analysis.  I [wrote a guide to doing exactly that](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) people seem to dig.  Maybe it'll help you, too.

Comment: Nice.   Always glad to read specific walk-throughs of debug tool usage as the options can be bewildering without some direction/guidance.

Comment: I'll check it out. I created a little test application and purposely did not release a couple of objects I had alloc. The instruments > leaks tool does not SEEM to show any problems. I may not be using it correctly. I am still very green with these tools.

Comment: The leaks tool will only find leaks *for which there are no pointers to the objects left anywhere in memory*.  If there happens to be a pointer to an object left on the stack that hasn't been overwritten yet, Leaks has no way of knowing that the pointer is no longer active and should not be considered!

Comment: Also, running the Static Analyzer from time to time can be a quick way to spot leaks that *do* meet the formal definition. To have it analyze your code, go to Xcode's **Build** menu and select **Build and Analyze**. It does a pretty amazing job.

Comment: Thanks for the link to your blog post on Heapshots. Very nice!

Answer (score 3):

Xcode has built-in tools, these are what developers typically use for debugging performance and memory issues.   You can access them via the Run -> Run With Performance Tool -> Instruments -> Leaks.   Also very useful in the NSZombies tool (here's one tutorial on using it:  http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/

Comment: ahhh.. there's one built in. Very nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In XCode you have an option, Build & Analyze (Shift-Cmd-A), that will check memory issues for you. This will find some of the memory management problems, but not all.

Note: Before running it, you may want to clean your target (Shift-Cmd-K) to make sure all project files are compiled.

After that you can use Instruments, with Leaks or Zombies as mentioned in the other answers.